# (gedit:3211): Gtk-WARNING **

Tags: ubuntu

I open a file with gedit from terminal.
Everytime I change something in this file or save it, I get the following message in terminal:

(gedit:3211): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Couldn't find anything via google and wasn't able to figure it by myself. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This looks like it might answer your question:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/376426/gtk-warning-calling-inhibit-failed

Comment: Thanks, but actually it doesn't. First, I never open gedit as a root, second, the occuring error message is not the same. I use Lubuntu btw.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help. However, one of the answers on that post (by Braiam) specifically talks about the exact same "org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files" error that you mention. Braiam mentions that it can be safely be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On newer debian based distros, you can install `gnome-session-bin` to install the needed `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.SessionManager.gschema.xml` file:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-bin
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't want to install gnome-session-bin, you should be able to run the following commands to add the needed file to your schemas:

```
mkdir schemafile;cd schemafile
apt-get download gnome-session-bin
ar xvf *
tar xvf data*
sudo mv ./usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.SessionManager.gschema.xml /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.SessionManager.gschema.xml
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/
cd ..
rm -R schemafile
```